# GCC Werror flag leads to "no option" error

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, windows-10, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags

I found the Wabsolute-value warning which I want to use as an error. However I get

```
cc1.exe:-1: error: error: -Werror=absolute-value: no option -Wabsolute-value
```

When I try the warning itself, I get :

```
:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wabsolute-value'; did you mean '-Wunused-value'?
```

I am using GCC on Windows 10. Calling `gcc --version` in `cmd` gives :

```
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The [default GCC page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) on warnings points to a different version of GCC, not 7.3.0 (but rather to the latest, probably). The manual page for warnings for 7.3.0 is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). This page does not speak of the `absolute-value` warning. It must be missing from 7.3.0 and must have been introduced later.